# Use Redis for a timeout queue or leaderboard

Tags: php, python, database, redis, queue

I want to use Redis basically like this, if it (hypothetically) accepted SQL:

```
SELECT id, data, processing_due FROM qtable WHERE processing_due < NOW()
```

where `processing_due` is an integer timestamp of some sort.

The idea is then to also remove completed "jobs" with something like:

```
DELETE from qtable WHERE id = $someid
```

Which Redis commands would I use on the producing ("insert") and consuming ("select, delete from") end?

I find that Redis can be used as a queue, but I don't want the answers in strictly the order they were inserted, but rather based on if "now" is past `processing_due`.

I imagine this is almost the same problem as a leaderboard?

<sub>(I try to wrap my head around how Redis works and it looks simple enough from the documentation, but I just don't get it.)</sub>

Would a decent solution be to do `ZADD qtable <timestamp> <UUID>` and then use the UUID as a key to store the (json) value under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Sorted Set](http://redis.io/topics/data-types), in which the score is your time (an integer as you've suggested), and then you query using [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore). Each member would be a Json representation of your "fields". For example: `{id:"1",data:"bla",processing_due:"3198382"}`

Regarding delete, just use [ZREM](http://redis.io/commands/zrem) when you find the relevant member to delete. pass your Json string as a parameter and you're OK.

A possibly better variant would be to just hold generated IDs as your member, and in a separate *String*-type key save pairs of your IDs along with the Json representation of your data. Just remember to maintain the two structs in sync.

Comment: Aha, this is another thing I found confusing. Is it considered good practice in REDIS land to delete based on value? (Not key as usually done in SQL.) Edit:   thanks!  This is just what I figured out on my own while writing the original question. But it felt so alien, I couldn't believe this was the correct way to do it. You confirming this "pattern" is a great help, thanks.

Comment: You actually delete based on a key, but your "key" here is essentially a "member" of the Sorted Set, not to be confused with a real redis "key" which is one string that represents your whole struct (be it a simple string, set, sorted set, hash or list)

Comment: Ah, cool. +1 on your comment, it might help also others in the future. In my case, the JSON document is small, so I will not use the double structure and *id* approach.

Comment: ***So to confirm, I'd use*** `SADD qtable '{id:"1",data:"bla",processing_due:"3198382"}'` ***then*** `ZRANGEBYSCORE qtable 0 3223335 WITHSCORES` ***and last*** `ZREM qtable '{id:"1",data:"bla",processing_due:"3198382"}'` ***?***

Comment: Hm, must be `ZADD qtable 3198382 '{id:"1",data:"bla",processing_due:"3198382"}`

Comment: Exactly (for both your comments, i.e. you must set the score of course in ZADD)